# adding a class to div, then onclick event with that class

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have an element that isn't clickable at first, but I'd like to make clicking on another div make it clickable.

What I did was

```
$("#div_1").addClass("selected");

$(".selected").click(function() {
    $("#block").animate({
        width: "70%",
        opacity: 0.4,
        marginLeft: "0.6in",
        fontSize: "3em",
        borderWidth: "10px"
    }, 1500);
});​
```

but this doesn't seem to work, I'm not sure what's wrong with this, maybe there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Well it depends upon where you're firing the event from, and where you're binding the click event. Please post some more javascript code.

Comment: works fine here..http://jsfiddle.net/hVvJK/1/.. You just have to make sure you are binding the click event handler after the element exists.. Or you can use delegation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try something like this:

$("#div_1").addClass("selected");

$("#div_1").click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('.selected') {
    $("#block").animate({
        width: "70%",
        opacity: 0.4,
        marginLeft: "0.6in",
        fontSize: "3em",
        borderWidth: "10px"
    }, 1500);
    }
});​
```

Also for usability purposes when you add the click-able functionality use this to make it appear click-able to the user:

```
$("#div_1").addClass("selected").css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **delegate** such cases... try using **.on()** and attach the event to the static parent..

Because when the class is added the event is already associated to when the DOM loads.. So delegating it will solve the problem.

```
$("#div_1").addClass("selected");

$('body').on("click", ".selected", function() {
     // Your code here
});​
```